# Protobuf illegal Wire type

Tags: javascript, c++, protocol-buffers

> protobuf.min.js:63 Uncaught Error: Illegal wire type for field
>   Message.Field .Data_new.vert: 5 (2 expected)

I get this message when I try to decode my binary file with protobuf.

vert.proto:

```
message Vertice_new{
    repeated float values = 1 [packed = true];
}
message Data_new{
    repeated Vertice_new vert = 1;
}
```

and in cpp i just put in a lot of raw data in the form of x,y,z,stress,strain ... and so on which are all floats and when I try to decode it on javascript side I get this weird message, it was working fine until we changed the input data, and now I don't know where to look for the fixing.

for references here my cpp code:

```
Data_new data_new;
for ... loopparameter is i ;  {  
    vert->add_values(nodes[i].pos.x + diffs[i].pos.x);
    vert->add_values(nodes[i].pos.y + diffs[i].pos.y);
    vert->add_values(nodes[i].pos.z + diffs[i].pos.z);
    vert->add_values(nodes[i].directStress.x);
    vert->add_values(nodes[i].directStress.z);
    vert->add_values(nodes[i].directStrain.x);
    vert->add_values(nodes[i].directStrain.z);
}
```

Comment: the first answer showed me, that the expected and currently available sizes of the fields are the problem, but we totally did not see, that it is data that is throwing the error, not vertice_new!! so there must be some other kind of issue, and I am still not able to resolve it

Comment: Double check that both the creator and consumer are using the exact same .proto file (and re-run protoc just to be sure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So finally I figured it out!  The problem was outside the code I posted ! I only set up an Ostream to write the binary data into, but instead I needed to actually state, that the file I want to write in is binary. So thank you all for your help and advice.

Comment: Thanks for that! It's gave me a clue to solve my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36969295/error-illegal-wire-type-for-field-message-field-protobuf-messagetypeack-source/36970795#36970795

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're serializing the field as if it's not `packed`.  Are you using an older version of the proto to serialize your data?

Wire type 5 is a 32-bit fixed-width field (fixed32, sfixed32, or float), which would match `repeated float values = 1`.  Wire type 2 is a length-delimited field (string, bytes, message, or packed repeated field), which matches what's in the proto you posted (`repeated float values = 1 [packed = true]`).

Comment: thanks for the input, yes I am using an older protobuf version, the newest was not working for me. But the proto data is the same on both sides. So how can I fix it? it sounds like I am supposed to just drop the [packed = true] and then it will work? Or am I mistaking?

Comment: Yes, `[packed = true]` seems to be your issue.  You're serializing the message without that option and trying to deserialize the data with it.

Comment: `// repeated float values = 1 [packed = true];`
  inline int values_size() const;
  inline void clear_values();
  static const int kValuesFieldNumber = 1;
  inline float values(int index) const;
  inline void set_values(int index, float value);` 
  inline void add_values(float value);

this is in the code in the header I use. so i guess it should work? how can i assure that the serialisation is working or not?

Comment: I just tried removing the `[packed = true]` statement from the proto which is used to unpack in javascript,  but nothing changed!
I am all out of ideas
so far I have tried looking into the header of my c++ code also what I described above, whereelse do I need to make sure everything is working?